# Extracting weights from SGD algorithm

Tags: python, pytorch

So I am implementing SGD for a binary classification problem. There are 2 classes of points and I want to plot the decision boundary but I'm not sure how to extract the weights from the code to plot it.

Here is the code:

```
def train_model(train_dl, model):
    # define the optimization
    criterion = nn.BCELoss(reduction='none')
    optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(net.parameters(), lr=0.1)
    # enumerate epochs
    for epoch in range(10):
        # enumerate mini batches
        for i, (inputs, targets) in enumerate(train_dl):
            # clear the gradients
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            # compute the model output
            yhat = model(inputs)
            # calculate loss
            loss = criterion(yhat, targets)
            # credit assignment
            loss.backward()
            # update model weights
            optimizer.step()
```

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You do not extract this information from the `SGD` optimizer, this information is part of your `model`.
What you can do, at test time, is generate a *grid* of points, compute their prediction using the trained `model` and then plot the grid points coloring them according to the prediction.